# Python + SQLite3 - Nested For Loops

Tags: python, sqlite, loops, for-loop

In the following code only the first pass of the outer for loop executes. Once the inner for loop completes one complete pass, subsequent passes of the outer for loop does not occur. Can someone help me in figuring out what is wrong?

Thanks,
Raj

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sqlite3

############################
#Create a comand object
############################
conn = sqlite3.connect('mxnet_sql.db')
c = conn.cursor()

#############################
#Do a select command
#############################
row1=[]
row2=[]
for row1 in c.execute('SELECT * FROM MIXED_NET_TABLE'):
    mnet_id = row1[0]
    mnet    = row1[1]
    for row2 in c.execute('SELECT * FROM AICM_TABLE'):
        mnet_aicm_id = row2[0]
        aicm         = row2[1]
        print("%s * %s" %(mnet_id, mnet_aicm_id))

print("When the inner fol loop complete the outer for loop does not run");
```

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the outer loop doesn't run anymore once the inner is completed?

Comment: Does `execute()` actually return anything? The documentation doesn't say.

Comment: You create only one DB cursor. A cursor can only work on one query (and the processed rows in it) at a time. If you let it execute another one it will forget the previous.

Comment: @Shawn Near beginning of https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html search for "iterator form".

Comment: @MichaelButscher He's using the cursor version.

Comment: @Shawn, in the example in the docs the "c" variable is also a cursor. This can be seen when looking at the sample codes above the "iterator form" example.

Comment: The execute command appears to be returning the rows of the table in the form of a tuple in the index variable **for index c.execute(...)  print(index)** (1, u'discipline_RL_E_tb2.supply', 2, 1)
(2, u'discipline_RL_E_tb2.Edrv_L_ss_wreal_R', 4, 3)
(3, u'discipline_RL_E_tb2.Ldrv_R_ss_wreal', 3, 2)

Comment: Why do you need to nest these queries at all?  The inner one has no dependency whatsoever on the outer one.  Perhaps your real code is different but your example makes it unclear what you're trying to do at all.  Depending on what problem you're *actually* trying to solve it might make more sense to use a subquery or a join.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I found an easier way to do this -

1. To answer po.pe's question, try this and yes I do get kicked out of the outer loop;-)
2. To Shawn's question - in a loop written this way -

   for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM MIXED_NET_TABLE'):
       mixed_net_table.append(row)

each row of the table is returned in "row" as a tuple. I subsequently create an array of tuples in "mixed_net_table". Basically I read then SQL table into python. The table is two dimensional in this case and can be accessed in the usual mixed_net_table[row][col] way...

Comment: Michael, corect I could have used an iterator but easier to just read in the table into python and manipulate these table